# Реализация функционала лайков, где и как правильно хранить информацию?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, алгоритм, веб-программирование, firebase

Есть бд, где есть посты и пользователи. У поста есть характеристика: сколько лайков. Пользователи могут оставлять и убирать лайки. Как правильно хранить информацию о том, какой пользователь кому поставил лайки? В голове только 1 реализация: у каждого юзера в бд добавить свойство "лайкнутые посты", в котором будут перечисляться айдишки постов, на которых от него уже стоит лайк (чтобы он не мог поставить второй, но мог убрать). Но мне кажется это не оптимизированным чтоли, как будто есть более элегантное решение хранение этой информации. Как это реализуют на реальных проектах?

Comment: Для пары пост/пользователь надо хранить один бит информации. Меньше не получится.

Comment: То бишь мое решение верное? Хранить у каждого пользователя в БД данные о его лайкнутых постах? Создать свойство, где будут айди лайкнутых?

Comment: Какая БД? Реляционная, документная?..

Comment: Свойство (колонка) "лайкнутые посты" позволит легко находить информацию для юзера. Но что если надо найти информацию для постов? Придётся сканировать всю таблицу/документ. | Если речь о РСУБД, то стоит рассмотреть стандартную many-to-many с промежуточной таблицей. Это позволит легко добавлять дополнительную информацию, например, дату, когда был сделан лайк.

Comment: у каждого комментария\поста есть ид, за него и цепляйте в отдельной таблице записи-лайки к комментариям. точь в точь так же как и сами комментарии к постам. а чтоб оправдать громоздкость, пусть это будут не лайки а например оценки(лайки и дизы 2 в 1), причем с диапазоном, скажем от +5 до -5. а чтоб не загадили бд ими за день, пусть будут платные - репутация\карма\баллы\монетки, пофигу... ну и есть еще возможность раздробить на разные суб оценки(1 - палец вверх\вниз, 2 сердечко целое\разбитое... ну и так далее) причем можно разные оценки привязать к разным валютам, чтоб интересней было :3

Comment: @puffleck, бд firebase (realtime database) от гугла. Задача: есть сайт с фильмами, его пользователи могут лайкать фильмы. БД фильмов и юзеров уже реализована, и я не знаю как правильно хранить информацию о лайках, чтобы во-первых - было как можно меньше нагрузки на БД, во-вторых - чтобы в будущем если нужно будет еще больше работать с лайками, где-то учитывать их и т.д. т.п., чтобы скан бд был также оптимизирован. Как реализуют лайки в соц сетях? Такая система мне и нужна.

Comment: Не пишите в комментариях. Редактируйте вопрос, добавляя необходимую информацию.

Comment: Предлагаю погуглить "firebase how to store likes": выдаются обсуждения на reddit и stackoverflow.

Comment: В [этой](https://dev.to/danielhe4rt/database-101-how-social-media-likes-are-stored-in-a-database-3oii) статье автор пришёл к использования специального типа данных counter (в ScyllaDB). В Firebase Realtime Database тоже есть какие-то счётчики (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters?hl=ru), думаю, стоит посмотреть в этом направлении.

Comment: `Как реализуют лайки в соц сетях? Такая система мне и нужна` ну возьмите первую попавшуюся под руку опен сорсную CMS и гляньте, там ведь логика не на пару строк кода... p.s. случайно заглянул(уведомление не пришло ибо одну "е" пропустили :3 )

Answer (score 0):

Создать поле у постов `likeUsers` при этом при лайке будет использоваться уникальный идентификатор пользователя `id` а при убирании лайка он будет автоматически удаляться.

Если есть и дизлайки то у постов должно быть еще одно поле, а там дальше как у `likeUsers`.

Также можно использовать Ваш вариант который мог бы пригодиться для выводы общей статистики по лайкнутым постам, но можно брать массив постов, искать по `likeUsers` указав уникальный идентификатор пользователя. Дальше делаете самостоятельно.